# Staging vs Online

Tags: content-management-system, sap-commerce-cloud

I am working in the Hybris CMS Cockpit. I have created a new Section slot on my homepage in staging, and when I preview, the new content is there but when I sync to online, it will not show. Any idea how to make this new slot visible online?

Answer (score 0):

Try to sync the **page** containing the new section slot. In your case this should my homepage. That might synch all child components and child slots of my homepage.

You might also check the catalog version in the HMC Cockpit via

`WCMS --> Content Slots --> Edit`

Maybe you can set the catalog version with the dropdown . I am not sure if that works.

***Hint:***
Pay attention with changes made in the HMC cockpit. Depending on your project strategy the **changes might be overwritten after an initialize** with values from the IMPEX files.

In that case you should add your new section slot to the corresponding IMPEX file.